# check if file is json, java

Tags: java, json, gson

Using Java is there an easy way to check whether a given file conforms to json format?

Using gson, the best i can do is:

```
private final JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
jsonElement = parser.parse(new FileReader(fileName));

    if (jsonElement.isJsonObject()) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
```

Any cleaner ideas?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Gson will throw [`JsonParseException`](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/tags/1.3/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/JsonParseException.html) if the JSON is not parseable. You just have to `catch` that with [`JsonParser#parse()`](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/tags/1.3/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/JsonParser.html#parse%28java.lang.String%29) in the `try`.

```
try {
    new JsonParser().parse(jsonSource);
    // Valid.
} catch (JsonParseException e) {
    // Invalid.
}
```